# onBlur attached to div getting called while moving from one input element to other present in the same div

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom-events, onblur

So I have a div and inside that div I have two input fields, like:

```
 <div>
    <input placeholder="Input1"/>
    <input placeholder="Input2"/>
 </div>
```

I wanted to call certain function whenever user clicks away from that div (not input fields).

So I attached onBlur event for that particular div, by giving it a tabIndex.

```
<div tabIndex="1" onClick={handleClick} onBlur={handleOnBlur}>
```

But now the onBlur event is getting triggered whenever I move from one input field to another input field residing in the same div.

I couldn't understand why this is happening. Also is there any better approach to achieve this sort of functionality.

**Codesandbox link to play-around**:
https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-carson-9rkj13

Comment: I would use an onClickOutSide hook instead. It will simplify the logic a-lot more. https://usehooks-ts.com/react-hook/use-on-click-outside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By passing in the `event` as a parameter to your `handleOnBlur` function, you can make use of `currentTarget` and `relatedTarget` properties, and discard events where the `relatedTarget` (`<input>`) is a child of the `currentTarget` (`<div>`).

For example:

```
const handleOnBlur = (event) => {
  if (event.currentTarget.contains(event.relatedTarget)) {
    return;
  }
  console.log("On blur for div called, setting false");
  setShowBtn(false);
};
```